# String search: has Eclipse IDE got a modern "find" UI (a la Firefox)

Tags: eclipse

One thing really really annoys me about the **Eclipse ide**: its find UI is so old style.

I would much prefer something like *Firefox* or *Safari*, that doesn't clutter my screen real estate with a useless window.

[image: Old-fashioned Eclipse find window]
<sub>(source: [eclipse-blog.org](https://www.eclipse-blog.org/wp-content/uploads/2007/04/blog_004.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Press ctrl+j. Is that what you want?
Hold down shift to go backwards.

Comment: Exactly what I meant. Thank you. My first question on StackOverflow has been anwered in 15 min. It rocks.

Comment: Agreed. Stackoverflow is awesome. 

I'm glad I could help. :)

Comment: Oh, also, when you get a right answer, remember to press the checkmark next to it. ;)

Answer (score 5):

you can also select the word you want to search and use ctrl+K, use shift to go backwards.

Comment: Works on whatever happens to be selected. What a great shortcut!

Comment: hell yeah, ctrl+j gives no useful effect on OS X but ctrl-K is a beast! :)

Answer (score 3):

And, if Eclipse's incremental search is not enough, you could always use a plugin like [Glance](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/1012).
From their site:

> Glance is an Eclipse plug-in providing extensible useful incremental text search in Eclipse. This plug-in supports the following features:
>
> - highlight all found matches
> - background search which never blocks text box
> - search in tables and trees
> - update matches when target content changed
> - new text containers can be supported through extension points
> - a lot of search settings

Answer (score 0):

You mean, like... Ctrl+F, and then Ctrl+K?

You don't have to use the Search menu.

On the other hand, if you just don't like the popup dialog, I think you're SOL for now.

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse "find" dialog does more than "find" on browsers you mentioned (e.g. search-and-replace, etc.) Having more options means more real estate to control them.